# How to embed MS Planner page without the extra chrome

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-planner

I want to embed a Planner page into a MS Teams tab using the "Website" tab typoe - because the Plan is native to a different Team and the MS Teams "Planner" tab type does not let you directly use Plans from other Teams sites.

However, I also *don't* want to include all the extra Planner/Sharepoint chrome as part of that tab.

Here's what I've found so far:

1. In old-school Sharepoint web parts, there was URL option for "IsDlg=1" which would do the needed and just give the web content without all the extra chrome. However, this apparently isn't supported in "modern" web pages - which are required in order to use the MS Planner web part. (Planner web parts apparently aren't supported by the older web part pages.)
2. If I create the web page using modern web page interface, then there's no option to hide the surrounding extra web page chrome, and the IsDlg=1 trick doesn't work.

Much appreciated if anyone has a solution to this. Extra credit if it doesn't require downloading the Sharepoint designer with the "Please don't use me: I'm deprecated!" warnings everywhere, but honestly I would take any solution at this point.

Thanks in advance!